# Image not loading correctly from BitmapImage in code behind

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Okay, I'm attempting to load an image to an Image control on my page. Now as far as I know, I know how to do this (the method I'm using has worked before). But for some reason it's not working this time. The image is not being loaded.

Okay, let's start with the XAML. [You can see it here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rje7f.jpg). Please note my excellent artistic skills. You can see that the top image is the left one on the screen and the bottom image is the right one. As you can also see, the image on the right is loaded in the XAML from a file in the Assets/Images folder. It should also be noted that we can take from this that the image loads okay - there aren't errors with the image. We can also see that the images are not blocked by anything (when the program runs, the right image shows just fine).

So the left image, 'image1' is the one that I'm loading from the code behind. [Here is the code behind for that page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGqf8.jpg). As you can see, there's not a lot. Yes I do use a view model, but it doesn't interface with the image at all (its only exposed properties are an Entity (for a selected item) and an ObservableCollection of entities (for the ItemsSource of a control)). As you can also see, I'm attempting to load the same image as is used for the static image (so I can say for sure that the image is okay for Silverlight).

If you're wondering about the BitmapCreateOptions line, that was something that someone suggested to me to add. I have tried removing it, but that doesn't seem to cause any difference.

The next question is - have I attempted to use the event handler for the failure? Yes I have. The error I get is 'AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR'.

I'm not sure what exactly this is about - I'm not loading from a network.

Can anyone offer assistance? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help but notice that in your XAML, you have a "../" at the start of the image path, but this is missing from the path you're using in code-behind.  Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried to call BeginInit and EndInit before and after setting the uri?

```
BitmapImage bmpImg = new BitmagImage();
bmpImg.BeginInit();
bmpImg.UriSource = new Uri(...);
bmpImg.EndInit();
```

Or use the constructor that takes an Uri. [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602473.aspx)